# Npm commands not running in SSH

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci

I really can't understand why on my machine via SSH I can execute npm commands and in deploy pipeline is not work? Wtf

```
Starting deploy
Already up to date.
v16.7.0
7.20.3
Deploy end
```

Result in CircleCI

```
Starting deploy
Already up to date.
deploy.sh: line 6: node: command not found
deploy.sh: line 7: npm: command not found
Deploy end
```

```
version: 2.1

# Define the jobs we want to run for this project
jobs:
  pull-and-build:
    docker:
      - image: arvindr226/alpine-ssh
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx "cd ~/apps/clm/core; sudo bash deploy.sh"

# Orchestrate our job run sequence
workflows:
  version: 2
  build-project:
    jobs:
      - pull-and-build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - Desenvolvimento
```

My bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting deploy"
cd ~/apps/clm/core
git pull

node -v
npm -v
echo "Deploy end"
```

Thanks a lot to anyone who helps.

I really don't understand what's going on I've tried looking for everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the **PATH**!

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no xxx@xx.xxx.xx.xx "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh; cd ~/apps/xxx/xxx; git pull; npm install; pm2 restart core client"
```

Comment: been running into the same issue! more details here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493295/410377